# convert a data frame to another data frame with 0s and 1s in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to convert data frame `A` to data frame `B`

```
A = data.frame(male = c(3, 5), female = c(1,2))

B = data.frame(male = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0), female = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1))
```

I have this method

```
new <- data.frame(male = c(rep(1, sum(male)), rep(0, sum(female))), female = c(rep(0, sum(male)), rep(1, sum(female))))
```

which gives me the desired data frame.

However, is there a better way to do this as my original data frame (A) is more complex than the example?

**UPDATE**

The data frame can be more complex in a way such as

```
A = data.frame(month = c("July", "August"), male = c(5, 3), female = c(2,1))
```

to be transformed to

```
data.frame(month = c(rep("July", 5), rep("July", 2), rep("Aug", 3), rep("Aug", 1)),
       male = c(rep(1, 5), rep(0, 2), rep(1, 3), rep(0, 1)),
       female = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 2), rep(0, 3), rep(1, 1)))

#    month male female
#1    July    1      0
#2    July    1      0
#3    July    1      0
#4    July    1      0
#5    July    1      0
#6    July    0      1
#7    July    0      1
#8  August    1      0
#9  August    1      0
#10 August    1      0
#11 August    0      1
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's hard to see what the relationship is between `A` and `B` to begin with. In `A`, male has one row each of "3" and "5", but in `B`, male has 8 rows of "1" and 3 rows of "0".

Comment: @shea, based on the transformation code, the sum of the numbers of male (8) turns into ones in the male and into zeros in the female, and vice versa for female.

Comment: In what way is it more complex? more elements, so you don't want to hard code it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in `tidyverse`.  `gather` the data into 'long' format, then expand the rows by `uncount`ing the 'val' column, create a column of 1s, grouped by 'month', create a sequence column ('ind'), `spread` from 'long' to 'wide'

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(A, sex, val, -month) %>%
    uncount(val) %>% 
    mutate(val = 1) %>%
    group_by(month = factor(month, levels = month.name)) %>% 
    mutate(ind = row_number()) %>%
    spread(sex, val, fill = 0) %>%
    select(month, male, female)
# A tibble: 11 x 3
# Groups:   month [2]
#   month   male female
#   <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 July       1      0
# 2 July       1      0
# 3 July       1      0
# 4 July       1      0
# 5 July       1      0
# 6 July       0      1
# 7 July       0      1
# 8 August     1      0
# 9 August     1      0
#10 August     1      0
#11 August     0      1
```

---

Or using similar logic with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(A), id.var = 'month')[, rep(1, value), 
 .(month, variable)], month + rowid(month) ~ variable, 
    value.var = 'V1', fill = 0)[, month_1 := NULL][]
```

#### data

```
A <- data.frame(month = c("July", "August"), male = c(5, 3), female = c(2,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inverse.rle`:

```
male<-c(1,0)
female<-c(0,1)
inverse.rle(list(lengths=sapply(A,sum),values=male))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
inverse.rle(list(lengths=sapply(A,sum),values=female))
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
```

Now let's apply this method to your complicated data:

```
split(A,A$month) %>% # split the data by months
lapply(function(x) data.frame(month=x[,1], # take each month's data, and create a data.frame for it with a month column, and the male and female columns with zeros and ones
  male=inverse.rle(list(lengths=sapply(x[,2:3],sum),values=c(1,0))), # if the data is very big, you might want to do they sapply here outside of this lapply, but I doubt this would make a big difference
  female=inverse.rle(list(lengths=sapply(x[,2:3],sum),values=c(0,1))))) %>%
do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, .) %>% # use do.call to take the list we created and bind it. I'm using dplyr's bind.rows because rbind formats the rows poorly.
arrange(sapply(test$month, function(x) which(x==month.name))) # the rows come out sorted by alphabetical order of months, so this fixes that.
```

result:

```
    month male female
1    July    1      0
2    July    1      0
3    July    1      0
4    July    1      0
5    July    1      0
6    July    0      1
7    July    0      1
8  August    1      0
9  August    1      0
10 August    1      0
11 August    0      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a package that deals with this but using base R we can use `apply`

```
do.call(rbind, apply(A, 1, function(x) {
   y <- as.numeric(x[-1])
  data.frame(month = rep(x[1], sum(y)), male = rep(c(1, 0), c(y[1], y[2])), 
             female = rep(c(0, 1), c(y[1], y[2]))) #Thanks @iod for simplifying
})) 


#    month male female
#1    July    1      0
#2    July    1      0
#3    July    1      0
#4    July    1      0
#5    July    1      0
#6    July    0      1
#7    July    0      1
#8  August    1      0
#9  August    1      0
#10 August    1      0
#11 August    0      1
```

Here for every row we create a dataframe where first column is the month. We calculate the number of 1's for male from "male" column and number of 0's is subtracted from the total sum - number of males and vice versa for females.

Comment: Q: why `sum(y)-y[1]` instead of just `y[2]`?

Comment: @iod oops yes, you are right. I missed that, I'll update the answer.  I believe there should also be a solution with some complicated `dplyr` chain.